# Please Arrange the type of testing in ascending order in which Tester should Test the application?

Tags: manual-testing, regression-testing, integration-testing, system-testing, smoke-testing

Could you please arrange these Below testing n which Tester should Test the application(where to start and where to end) in Ascending order with Example of each one of them.

```
1.Smoke testing 
2.Sanity testing 
3.Regression testing 
4.Integration testing 
5.System testing 
6.Acceptance testing 
7.Unit testing 
8. Compatibility testing
```

**NOTE:Please add any type of testing if i have missed**

Comment: Different test are performed at different times by different people (or in parallel), or skipped for some iterations. And few types or tests are missing, like load and performance tests. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am not sure if this question should be closed (it might be). Problem with it is not that it is not answerable: problem with it is what **it is wrong question to ask**. As I said you will run different tests, depending of what you want to accomplish and measure. If you don't tell us what is your goal, right answer is [mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)) - [non-answer](http://webpages.charter.net/sn9/literature/mu.html): **the context of the question becomes too small for the truth of the answer**

Comment: This seems awfully like an exam question. We are not here to answer test questions - what ordering would you use, what is the official answer, and what do you not understand about the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Why?

Order doesn't make a lot of sense unless you can tell us context please.

Also some of those things are not of the same type - you can have smoke tests for Integration testing as well as for Regression and Acceptance testing so there are multiple categories here.

More generally the standard cycle is unit -> integrated -> acceptance -> performance & security.

Instead I would focus on the Agile Testing Quadrants and the Test Pyramid.

[image] [image]

For examples I would read:

[image]

Comment: edited the Question...........

Comment: better.  although developers should be running writing and running unit tests in a TDD/BDD style.  Compatibility testing is made up.  probably UAT.